# star-rating do not show properly

Tags: php, css, wordpress, elementor

Used woocommerce and Elementor to create [this shop page](https://mobilekhalijfars610.com/%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B4%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%AE%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AC-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3/), but star rating symbols dont show properly . I can not find right file to start edit
I know if add `font-family: star;` to css file it would be OK but I do not know where to add this code.

what should I do? where should i search to solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: the green stars?

Comment: Your question contains more problems than just the star symbol problem. If you don't know where to add custom css for your pages, please figure out these issues first and come back and update your question.

Comment: I use elementor and know how to add , but css files has different version and my changes did not shows on website

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress admin console, go to Appreance > Editor or Theme Editor.
Mostly, your themes css file 'style.css' will be opened for editing. If not select the stylesheet from right side (under Theme Files).
Paste following code at the end of the file and press the "Update File" button under the editor.

```
.product-rating__stars span {
    font-family:star;
}
```